# **Math/Stableswap Formula** Explaining the subsitution of "Chi" to get Stableswap invariant formular

Tags: math, stablecoins

**Hello, I'm having a trouble of understanding this operation:**

In [Curve.fi Stable Swap's paper](https://curve.fi/files/stableswap-paper.pdf), page 5, they substitue

[image]

into this formular

[image]

With some simplification step, we get the Stableswap invariant:

[image]

**Can somebody show me details of the the process to get to the latest formular please?** I have tried many times but still could not come to it. Thank you!

Comment: You plug in chi and then divide both sides by (prod_xi / D) and you should be there.

Comment: @ikijong Oh man, thank you very much! It is quite simple but I'm so dumb haha!

Comment: All good. I  derived that before, that's how I knew.